# Replace the Indexes without Loop

Tags: java

My Question is :

First I have String variable of 1000 character, and I have another set of String variable of 1000 character
1] In First Set of Variable contains "1110000XXXXX0001111...." like this and so on, till 1000

2] In The second Set of Variable contains "1110000101010001111..." like this and so on till 1000

3] I need to get the position of X in first Variable and replace the Value of similar position from the second variable

For ex : 1st Variable of data "000XXX000X0"
         2nd Variable of data "00011000010"
The X should be replaced by the values which is in the position in 2nd set of data.

NOTE : TO BE DONE WITHOUT LOOP 
because if we put loop its runs 1000 times in a loop and 'X' may be anywhere in 1000 characters in the String

For ex: 1 Record 1000 Times
if 100K Records means 1000*100K (PERFORMANCE FAILS)

So need solution for it.

Kindly Help me out with this.

My Code is :

```
 String    sInputStr="0X11XXXXX000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000X000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011";

 String sDbStr="0111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011";


          int iLength=sInputStr.length();
            for(int i=0;i<iLength;i++){
                if(sInputStr.charAt(i)=='X'){

                }else{
                    if(i>sDbStr.length()){
                        break;
                    }else{
                        sChar[i] = sInputStr.charAt(i);                         
                    }
                }
            }//End of For
            sVal=String.valueOf(sChar);
            System.out.println("sVal == " +sVal);
```

Help Me friends

Comment: I can't figure out why to make sInputStr = sDbStr so superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is something like this

```
    class FirstApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sDbStr="0111111110000001234000000000000011";
        StringBuilder sNewStr= new StringBuilder("011111111000000XXXX00000000000001112");
        String findStr = "X";
        int lastIndex = 0;
        System.out.println("Starting");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String result = replaceValues("X", sDbStr, sNewStr);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Result");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(endTime-startTime));
    }

    public static String replaceValues(String toReplace, String fromStr, StringBuilder toStr) {
        int lastIndex = toStr.indexOf(toReplace);
        if(lastIndex != -1){
            toStr.replace(lastIndex,lastIndex+1,Character.toString(fromStr.charAt(lastIndex)));
            System.out.println(toStr);
            return replaceValues(toReplace, fromStr, toStr);
        } else {
            return toStr.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

sample result:

```
Starting
0111111110000001XXX00000000000001112
01111111100000012XX00000000000001112
011111111000000123X00000000000001112
011111111000000123400000000000001112
Result
011111111000000123400000000000001112
```

**UPDATE** Updated solution to ensure less execution time using stringBuilder and recursion

Comment: How is it any better then using the loops? Also, you are replacing in the String which are immutable and hence it is creating a new String every time you are replacing a character.

Comment: You can change it with a String Builder.So not  to create new strings every time. Loops are limited to the number of replacements required

Comment: Yes you can change it to String Builder. I commented on your original solution which uses String and not String Builder! :)

Comment: Hi @user2004685 i have update Solution using StringBuilder

Comment: Thanks Taj Ahmed, But comparing to For loop which i have mentioned above code, The timing varies. I calculated of For Loop and got 1ms and if i process with while loop, i get 3ms, Time increases here, problem is to reduce the timing

Comment: @ShankaraNethranS.N i have updated the solution using recursion which takes less than 125ms to replace 1000 character string

Answer (score 0):

If `X` point to one value, like as mentioned `X` replace by `1`. Go for `string.replaceAll` function.

ie.

```
        String oriString="000XXX000X0";
        String replaceOne=oriString.replace('X','1');
        System.out.println(replaceOne);
```

Comment: @Vyacheslav sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: No sir, that'd be incorrect. He means to replace characters in the first string marked by 'X' by the characters at the same position in the second string.

Comment: But can't X be both 0 and 1 depending on the second array? Example, `array1: 000XXX000` & `array2: 000101000`. Only if I understood it correctly.

Comment: yes, user2004685 and steady_daddy you are right. Need solution as you guys said

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly then you want to replace the values of X in your first array with the values from seconds array at the same positions. For Example, `array1: 000XXX000` & `array2: 100101001`. Then array1 should finally be `000101000`.

Here is a simple code snippet to achieve this:

```
char[] arr1 = sInputStr.toCharArray();
char[] arr2 = sDbStr.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++)
     if(arr1[i] == 'X')
          arr1[i] == arr2[i];
```

Comment: Though the Loop goes as size of that String Value Sir. My Problem is that only.

Comment: It will only iterate through the length of First String i.e. 1000 Times and not 1000*1000 Times. Even if you go for replace/replaceAll, it will iterate over your string internally.

Comment: Yeah understood , For 1 time Process the Loop is OK, but i will replace the Values of First Variable more than 1000 times ..

Comment: Even if it is 1000*1000, it should take less than a second. Hope you find a better way of doing it.

Comment: No User, I didnt say like that, For 1 Process its taking 1ms, So for more than 1000 process it takes more time Right, Am asking any other way for this , But its ok I got the Solution Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to search for the index of the occurrence of the character say 'X' and copy all the characters from second string into the first as long as we find 'X'. Repeat the process till the last occurrence of 'X'.

```
public class Test
{


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
 String s1 = "0X11XXXXX000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000X000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011";

 String s2= "0111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011";

 char a[] = s1.toCharArray();
 int i = s1.indexOf('X', 0);

 while(i!=-1)
 {

    while(a[i] == 'X'){
        a[i] = s2.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }

    i = s1.indexOf('X',i+1);

}

s1 = new String(a);

System.out.println("result: "+s1);


   }
 }
```